# Spring Boot Test is not using test properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, apache-kafka

I Am using spring boot 2.0.1 , but when I perform the test, it seems to start, before the test class, also the main class. 
In my main class I use spring cloud config, discovery service and kafka.
I have this test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:bootstrap-test.properties")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DaemonLogServiceTest {

@Autowired
private LogService logService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ResultLog log = new ResultLog();
    log.setNumberOfRowsProcessed(10);
    log.setLastCodOperProcessed(1000);
    log.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS.name());
}

@Test
public void whenOperationsProcessedThenLog() {
    logService.newActivity(10, 1000L, Status.SUCCESS);
    ResultLog log = logService.saveActivity();
    Assert.assertNotNull(log);
}

}
```

When I run it, it seems to start the Main method (not from test) that uses Kafka and Spring cloud discovery. 
Here is the output:

```
018-06-19 14:45:01.397 ERROR 17124 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at []
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers' in value "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}"
```

I only use Kafka in the main application, not in test classes.
My property file is:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema.sql
daemon.delay=2000
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = false
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = false
spring.cloud.config.enabled = false
eureka.client.enabled=false
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue lies in `@SpringBootTest` which loads your main application context with your main `ConfigurationClass`. So then even you are not using Kafka, Spring tries to initialize your kafka beans which are missing: `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property.

You can run your tests by specifying a separate config class without kafka beans and other unnecessary beans using `@ContextConfiguration`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:bootstrap-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = LogServiceTestConfig.class)
public class DaemonLogServiceTest {

@Autowired
private LogService logService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ResultLog log = new ResultLog();
    log.setNumberOfRowsProcessed(10);
    log.setLastCodOperProcessed(1000);
    log.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS.name());
}

@Test
public void whenOperationsProcessedThenLog() {
    logService.newActivity(10, 1000L, Status.SUCCESS);
    ResultLog log = logService.saveActivity();
    Assert.assertNotNull(log);
}

}
```

Comment: maybe it would be helpful, if you would post also your configuration file, where you specify Profile "test"

Comment: I created a new test config class and now it is working, without bringing up the whole kafka context.